# mySQL, website statistics: unique daily visits

Tags: mysql

I have a table `statistics` in database:

```
CREATE TABLE `statistics` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `address` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `ip` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

To obtain daily webpage visits I am using a following query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, "%Y-%m-%d"), COUNT(*)
FROM `statistics`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

How to modify the query to obtain daily visits unique by IP?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to count distinct IPs like the following

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, "%Y-%m-%d"), COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`)
FROM `statistics`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

If you want to treat null as a single IP we have to make a slightly different query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, "%Y-%m-%d"), COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) + SUM(ISNULL(`ip`))
FROM `statistics`
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Comment: That is what I am looking for! Thanks!

Comment: And how to treat NULL IPs as single IP? With your proposal NULLs are not counted.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `IP`in `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, "%Y-%m-%d"), IP, COUNT(*)
FROM `statistics`
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```